# Short hand for nesting repetitive arguments

Tags: c#, arguments, operators

Are there any shorthands for arguments with a common reference?

Something like:

`If(sourceInt != (thisInt || (thatInt && otherInt) ) {....}`

Instead of writing out overly large arguments:

```
If(thatInt == otherInt)
{
    commonInt = thatInt;
}

If(sourceInt != thisInt || sourceInt != commonInt)
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Loops or [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) are the two options that come to my mind immediately.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @promanski Cleaner code for the most part. I don't see other advantage to it otherwise~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such shorthand. You can come close to it, though, using LINQ with array aggregates. For example, this

```
if (myInt == 1 || myInt == 20 || myInt == 75) {
    ...
}
```

can be expressed as

```
if ((new[] {1, 20, 75}).Any(i => myInt == i)) {
    ...
}
```

and this

```
if (myInt != 1 && myInt != 20 && myInt != 75) {
    ...
}
```

can be converted to

```
if ((new[] {1, 20, 75}).All(i => myInt != i)) {
    ...
}
```